# Объекты в vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, объекты, vuex

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с vue. Есть объект, который получаю из API, нужно сравнить id из food с `this.$route.params.id`. Пытаюсь делать таким образом:

```js
return this.allMenu.food.find(item => item.id == this.$route.params.id)
```

в `computed`, но выдает ошибку `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134344/discussion-on-question-by-----vue-js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вызывается метод массива `find` не на массиве, а на объекте.

Поэтому код нужно изменить на такой.

```
return Object.values(this.allMenu.food).find(item => item.id == this.$route.params.id)
```

Кроме того, когда шаблон будет пытаться отрисоваться и вызовет соответствующий геттер, данные с API еще не факт, что придут. Поэтому необходимо добавить дополнительную проверку вида

```
return Object.values(this.allMenu.food)?.find(item => item.id == this.$route.params.id) ?? []
```

Либо, если новый синтаксис в вашей среде не поддерживается, так

```
return this.allMenu && this.allMenu.food ? Object.values(this.allMenu.food).find(item => item.id == this.$route.params.id) : []
```